HELP! Bitcoin bought back in 2017
Can somebody help me recover my Bitcoin I bought it that years ago before it took off about $60 I have the receipts but the ink is a little faded I kind of make out the wallet address but I have no way of accessing it can anyone help me in the situation on the steps to take through one of those Bitcoin ATMs. I went to the store and they refuse to help.
